# How to have the assess to clinical data(PROSPECT)

Tags: data-request

I am learning causal inference and I want to use a very popular dataset(the dataset is created in 1999). I find the webpage of it and many papars citing it. However, I never ever to find the download link. I wish someone could help me about it. It is a dataset belongs to `clinicaltrials.gov`.

The website about [`Prevention of Suicide in Primary Care Elderly: Collaborative Trial (PROSPECT)`](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT00279682?id=NCT00279682&draw=2&rank=1&load=cart). The funniest thing is that the website allows me to download the query results instead of dataset of study.

The paper using it [Reducing Suicidal Ideation and Depressive Symptoms in Depressed Older Primary Care Patients: A Randomized Controlled Trial](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a736/04ca8fd79819e5f466032d6f4732c05e3922.pdf)

If you guys can give me some advice about it or provide me several causal inference dataset(experiment data and observational data), I will be very grateful!

Comment: Hi @Travis, have you read https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/resources/download?

Comment: @sboysel I did, so I write: "The funniest thing is that the website allows me to download the query results instead of dataset of study."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the dataset linked in this page?

http://research.bmh.manchester.ac.uk/biostatistics/research/data/

> Data from this trial are available on the Biometrics journal website as supplementary material to the paper:
>
> ```
> Ten Have TR, Joffe MM, Lynch KG, Brown GK, Maisto SA, Beck AT. Causal mediation analyses with rank preserving models. Biometrics, 2007, 63(3), pp926–34.
> ```

Direct link: http://www.biometrics.tibs.org/datasets/060225CF_biomweb.zip

Archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20200131081512/http://www.biometrics.tibs.org/datasets/060225CF_biomweb.zip

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thank you a lot. BTW, How did you find it? I spend about 5 days and find nothing usefull. I did search several papers using this dataset, but none of them provided the dataset. @philshem

Comment: @Travis internet search with the full text "Prevention of Suicide in Primary Care Elderly: Collaborative Trial (PROSPECT)" and DuckDuckGo instead of Google. Was at the bottom of the first page.

Comment: Really appreciate for your method!